# How to train support vector machine in matlab ?

Tags: matlab

SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training,Group);
Above command is availble for SVM traning, but how to prepare 'Training' and 'Group'.
I am working on digital mammograms for breast cancer detection. I have done preprocessing and features extraction. And now i want to classify the mammograms in three classes.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `fitcsvm` instead of `svmtrain`, as it's an old function that will be deprecated.

`fitcsvm(X,y)` takes as input X, a NxM matrix, where N are the observations and M are the variables, and y, a Nx1 matrix, of the targets.

Check out the [fitcsvm](https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) page for extensive examples and explanations.